# Stored audio files using Android WebView is not working

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

I am trying to store audio files binary string into sdcard using android webview. But when I try to play an audio file in my mobile filemanager, the audio file is not playing. I am using JavaScript Interface for getting and saving audio file binary data into sdcard. I don't want to use an android download manager or another download manager for downloading files. I need to fix the below-posted code for audio play.

Here is code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private WebView MCwv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String urlText ="http://susbd.com/bd.php?url=http://banglasongs.fusionbd.com/downloads/download.php?file=mp3/bangla/Romantic_Hitz/Tip_Tip_Brishti-Konika.mp3";
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Getting String...");
        MCwv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mcwv);
        WebSettings settings = MCwv.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setUserAgentString("Opera/9.80 (Android; Opera Mini/36.2.2254/119.132; U; id) Presto/2.12.423 Version/12.16)");
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        settings.setSupportZoom(true);
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            settings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
        }

        MCwv.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");

        MCwv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            {
                MCwv.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.showHTML(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML);");
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        MCwv.loadUrl(urlText);
    }

    public class MyJavaScriptInterface
    {
        @JavascriptInterface
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void showHTML(String OutPut)
        {
            try {
                File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/mydl");
                if (!dir.exists()) {
                    dir.mkdirs();
                }

                File file = new File(dir, "This_my_test_file.mp3");
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }

                FileOutputStream save = new FileOutputStream(file);
                save.write(Html.fromHtml(OutPut).toString().substring(6).getBytes()); //html decoded and removed 6 string <html>
                save.flush();
                save.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```